# How to add subviews to a frame from other class?

Tags: java, swing, view, hierarchy, conventions

First of all, I'm not looking for a solution, I'm asking what is the most acceptable way for doing this.
Now I have a main frame which has a drawing JPanel and a couple JScrollPane just for logging things. 
I have put all log related views in a class and added to the main frame like this:

```
logViews = new LogViews(this);
```

I think I should not add the whole class to the object, but how else can I make it work? Should I extend the main frame or make an interface? 
The log views need to communicate with the main panel too, so it must be connected both ways.

Ok so if its not clear enough:

LogViews is a custom class I made, it looks something like this, but with more JLists:

```
public class LogViews {
        private DefaultListModel logModel;
        private JList<String> logList;

        public LogViews(MainFrame frame){
            logModel = new DefaultListModel();
            logList = new JList();
            logList.setModel(logModel);
            JScrollPane logListScroll = new JScrollPane(logList);
            frame.add(logListScroll, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
}
```

It works, I just wonder if I can do it without adding the MainFrame in the constructor.

Comment: 1) What is `LogViews`, a custom component?  2) _"a couple JScrollPane just for logging things."_ What exactly does that mean? Are there text areas in side them? 3) How in the world does this `logViews = new LogViews(this);` show us that you've added it to frame?

Comment: I have added a simple example

Comment: So Ultimately, LogViews is just a `JList` am I correct? And what exactly was the question about what you want to do with it?

Comment: Also, did you want that class to show up in the `MainFrame` or have as a separate frame?

Comment: I need it inside, the whole point of this is to separate some code, because the class of the main frame is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `LogViews` a `JDialog` something like this

```
public class LogViews extends JDialog {
    private DefaultListModel logModel;
    private JList<String> logList;

    public LogViews(JFrame frame, boolean modal){
        super(frame, true);
        logModel = new DefaultListModel();
        logList = new JList();
        logList.setModel(logModel);
        JScrollPane logListScroll = new JScrollPane(logList);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(logListScroll);
        pack();
    }
}
```

You can make it open with the click of a button

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new LogViews(MainFrame.this, true);
    }
}
```

What you can do to allow it to *"communicate"* with the `MainFrame` is just to have it as an inner class so it has access to all the class members of the `MainFrame`. Other than that, it's hard to offer a complete solution, because have provided much as to what needs to be communicated.

---

If you want it to appear in the `MainFrame`, you can just `LogViews` a `JPanel` and add that panel to the `MainFrame`. Again, having it as an inner class of `MainFrame` so it can access all the fields of `MainFrame`

---

**EDIT**

What you can also do, if you want is as a separate class, is have a `setter`. Like

```
public void setLogModel(DefaultListModel model) {
    logList.setModel(model);
}
```

And/Or a couple methods to add and remove from the list

```
public void addToList(String element) {
    logModel.addElement(element);
}
```

Then just call those methods from the `MainFrame`. But for your scenario, I would just make the `LogViews` a `JPanel`, instead of the `JDialog`, and instantiate it in the `MainClass` and add it to your `MainFrame`. Something like

```
public class LogViews extends JPanel
    private DefaultListModel logModel;
    private JList<String> logList;

    public LogViews(){
        logModel = new DefaultListModel();
        logList = new JList();
        logList.setModel(logModel);
        JScrollPane logListScroll = new JScrollPane(logList);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(logListScroll);
    }

    public void addToList(String element) {
        logModel.addElement(element);
    }

    public void setLogModel(DefaultListModel model) {
        logList.setModel(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, so if its not a problem to give it the frame, it will work thanks!